# Want to change Currency with Language on language change

Tags: i18n-l10n, commerce

I am new in Drupal 7.

I am working on `drupal commerce` module. I want to built a site for multi-language and also for multi currency. I am using `i18n` and `Commerce multi currency` module as they gave me `language selector` block and `currency selector` block and both functionality working fine individually.

But I want to change both `Language` and `Currency` on language select, like if I select English language currency will automatically change to USD and if I select Denmark language currency will automatically change to DKK and so on.

So is there any possibility to change the relevant currency with language change on Language select?

Please help.

Comment: Thanks @Mash.  Believe it or not, you gave me the answer to my question. I was trying to add the currency selector and I didn't realize there was a block for it! :)